# Test and add a zero to single digit variable during initialization

Tags: bash, unix, initialization, digits

Data returned by a dbus command are stored in an array.

I initialize both variables with specific array value by using

```
var1=${array[7]}
var2=${array[9]}
```

If ${array[7]} or ${array[9]} are "< 10" and echo on var1 or returns :

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

And I would like to obtain

```
00
01
02 
03
...
```

Is there an easy way to add this specific digit during the initialization by using seq or an other command ?

Comment: Have to be careful: with bash arrays, the index is evaluated in arithmetic context, so numbers with leading zeroes are handled as octal: `x[08]=foo` results in `bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")`

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in formatting operator, but it's easy enough with `printf`.

```
printf '%02i\n' "${array[@]}"
```